# Holomorphic function equal to polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this question

> Let $h$ an holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$ and suppose that 
>   $$|h(z+7) -3|^2\leq |z-1|^9 + 42$$
>   for all $z$ such that $|2z+63|>177$. Prove that $h$ is a polynomial.

How can I attack this problem? I can't see how because I wanted to use the Liouville theorem, but it isn't bounded in all $\mathbb{C}$. Could anyone give me an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

The meromorphic function $g(z) = h(z+7)/(z-1)^9$ is bounded outside some disk, so its singularity at $\infty$ is removable.  Being a meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere, it is a rational function,
and so $h(z)$ is a rational function with no poles in $\mathbb C$, i.e. a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z) = h(z+7)-3$. Outside of the bounded domain $|2z+63| \le 177$, $|f(z)|$ is $O(|z|^9)$. By the well-known estimate derived from the Cauchy integral formula for the $n$th derivative of a holomorphic function, any entire function which is bounded in absolute value by a polynomial in $|z|$ for $|z|$ sufficiently large has a derivative which is identically zero-- in other words, is a polynomial. Therefore $f$ is a polynomial, and equivalently $h$ is a polynomial.

Comment: What means $O(|z|^9)$?

Comment: [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)